# Using DeleteCases with multiple AstronomicalData properties

Tags: list-manipulation, curated-data, astronomy, filtering

I am attempting to use `AstronomicalData` and `DeleteCases` together to remove invalid cases of two properties while listing the corresponding name which the data belongs to.

I can only selectively choose one of the two properties in which to remove invalid cases from.

An example of two selected properties with the first property being filtered;

```
DeleteCases[Transpose[{
 AstronomicalData["Exoplanet", P1], AstronomicalData["Exoplanet", P2], AstronomicalData["Exoplanet"]
 }],{_Missing,_,_}],
```

The issue is having a limitation of defining either `P1` or `P2` as the chosen property to remove invalid cases from. I have tried various ways of correcting this and can't apply it to both properties.

I can switch which property it acts upon by swapping the slot _Missing is defined in like this;

```
{_Missing,_,_}
{_,_Missing,_}
```

Defining both slots doesn't apply the function to either individual property like this;

```
{_Missing,_Missing,_}
```

How can I achieve being able to filter the results where if either property has an invalid value the data is dismissed?

Comment: `{___, _Missing, ___}` this should delete any row wit Missing value. You can use `FreeQ`/`MemberQ` with `Pick` or with `Sow`+`Reap` too.

Comment: @Kuba That solution is working fine. I'm unfamiliar with `Sow`+`Reap`, I'll have to look further into them. Do you mind mentioning why the solution only works while _Missing is defined in `#2`?

Comment: `BlankNullSequence` is the key, take a look at documentation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I have not found good duplicate, and there is none in [curated-data](/questions/tagged/curated-data) so maybe one can find this useful.

```
data = RandomChoice[{1, 2, 3, 4, Missing[]}, {100, 3}];

n = 100;

DeleteCases[data, {___, _Missing, ___}]~Do~{n} // Timing // First
Cases[data, {_?NumberQ ..}]~Do~{n} // Timing // First
Pick[data, FreeQ[#, _Missing] & /@ data, True]~Do~{n} // Timing // First
Reap[Map[If[FreeQ[#, _Missing], Sow[#]] &, data]][[2, 1]]~Do~{n} // Timing // First
data /. {___, _Missing, ___} -> Sequence[]~Do~{n} // Timing // First
```

> ```
> 0.004289
>
> 0.009231
>
> 0.014014
>
> 0.022367
>
> 0.000167
> ```

Comment: +1, don't know why you made it community wiki! My favorite version is Missing, it is `data /. {___, _Missing, ___} -> Sequence[]~Do~{n} // Timing // First`

Comment: @Anon :) feel free to add an answer :) About wiki, I don't know, I usually do this when I feel this is a duplicate and the answer is not really the best one. :)

Comment: Alright, maybe it's the right thing to do. It does encourage others to pitch in, but I'm so unused to it I didn't know how to interpret it.

Comment: Standalone `{___,_Missing,___}` works fine, a bit less bulky than the alternatives. As there is limited data I don't think in this instance the alternatives will provide any benefit, unless I'm wrong, I will test them all to find any benefits nonetheless.